# Return list of a class items from other list controller? [Web API]

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to return a Class list objects from other class controller? I want to create a route that returns list of Apartments that are located in the house specified by ID

```
    [Route("api/House/{id}/Apartments")]
    public List<Apartment> Get()
    {
        return Apartments;
    }
```

I try this in HouseController, but it shows an error - Apartments does not exist in current context. Is it possible to make Apartments list accessible from house controller, or this is wrong way to do it?

```
public class House
{
    public string house_address { get; set; }
    public List<Apartment> apartments = new List<Apartment>();
    public Guid Id = Guid.NewGuid();
}
public class Apartment
{
    public string apartment_number { get; set; }
    public House House { get; set; }    
    public Guid Id = Guid.NewGuid();                                   
}
```

---

Controllers:

```
  public class HousesController : ApiController
   { static List<House> Houses = new List<House>()
     public List<House> Get()
     { return Houses; }
   }
public class ApartmentsController : ApiController
   {static List<Apartment> Apartments = new List<Apartment>()
 }
```

Comment: May be you can encapsulate Apartments in a service and use DI

Comment: The Get Apartments method needs to sit in the `ApartmentsController ` or you need to return the static field `ApartmentsController .Apartments`.

Comment: ApartmentsController.Apartments works, but it returns all apartments, any way to return only those who match the Id? .Where does not work for it